# How do I put my ProgressBar Spinner ontop of a button in XML?

Tags: android, button, progress-bar, spinner

I made a soundboard app where when I click a button, it plays a sound by setting the onClick to Button_sound.start. I want a progress spinner ontop of the button only while the sound is playing. How do I put the spinner ontop of the button in xml instead of above or below the button? and How do I make the spinned only show while the sound is playing? Thanks greatly as I am very new to developing and please make your answers as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please post the code that you already got so it will be bit easier to come up with solution.
You can set the orientation of the linearlayout(which contains your spinner and button)to be vertical.this will align spinner on top of button.
Make sure you have code for spinner written before button inside that linear layout.